# Does binding a VAO really take 1ms or is my stopwatch class broken?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, lwjgl

Here is my stopwatch class

```
public class Benchmark {
static long starttime;
static ArrayList<Long> timeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
public static void start() {
    glFinish();
    starttime = System.nanoTime();
}

public static void stop() {
    glFinish();
    timeList.add(System.nanoTime() - starttime);
    if(timeList.size() > 10) {
        Long total = (long) 0 ;
        for(Long time : timeList) {
            total += time;
        }
        System.out.println(((float)total / timeList.size())/1000000 ); 
        timeList.clear();
    }
}
```

and here's the simple benchmark

```
    Benchmark.start();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    Benchmark.stop();
```

I am reading values of 1ms, how is that possible? Is my stopwatch broken? I notice if I comment out some draw calls, then it reads lower values of .2ms, which is weird because it shouldn't affect this.

Is binding really this expensive or what is the problem here?

Comment: Why wouldn't draw calls affect this? If you didn't use `glFinish()` **then** draw calls wouldn't affect this, but you do ;)

Comment: I'm more interested on the openGL code than your watch. Still, why are you using glFinish(). Are you using the legacy openGL ?

Comment: Actually, the **only** reason that it takes you anything over nanoseconds (talking modern hardware here) would be because you are using `glFinish()`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Not necessarily, validation can have a measurable overhead. Though vertex arrays are typically the cheapest/simplest resources to validate. Still, you have a good point... the majority of that measured time is the result of `glFinish (...)`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm just presuming that the drivers are any good :L but the `glFinish` call would actually come out to be very expensive (of course not the actual call itself, just the side effect) because it waits for any framebuffer/connection/state changes to be completed before returning. That would mean any draw calls or buffer bindings.

Comment: Do not measure performance this way, if you have a GL 3.3 era driver, use timer queries instead. They are not a hardware feature, they just require a sufficiently up to date driver.

Comment: guys look at my start method. I flush the buffer completely before I do any timing, so I'm suppose to only be timing what's inbetween start and stop, so no outside draw calls should affect this.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman that will only give you GPU based timings though; if you want the time taken that a user will see, you should use a CPU based timer.

Comment: Since you're asking about your stopwatch class: The way I read it, it always prints out the average of the last 10 measurements, right? So if you're looking at that value, wouldn't the result depend on what you did during the previous 9 measurements?

Comment: One final note... you are binding a VAO, not a VBO. VAOs are significantly more complicated, because they setup a lot of states. Binding VAOs is much more expensive than VBOs, but still cheaper than FBOs or GLSL Programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code execution is probably taking the length of time you are getting because of your calls to `glFinish`.

The reason for this is that `glFinish` causes your program to stall until all connection/framebuffer/state changes have been completed: this includes any draw calls or buffer bindings.

Comment: i call glFInish in my start(), so the buffer should be clear of anything before the timing happens. Right... did you notice that?

Comment: @BlazArt yes, but you also call it after the vertex array binding. The actual time it takes for that function to complete will be much less than the time it takes for all the side-effects of that function to be complete.

Comment: @BlazArt Honestly, just use GL Timer Query Objects and avoid all of this nonsense. They are much higher resolution, give you the exact amount of time a command takes ***in the pipeline*** and if you wait until they are finished to read the result back, you will not stall the pipeline.

Comment: @BlazArt yes, I did notice that, and it makes no difference to my answer. There are quite a few side-effects server side in a vertex-array binding.

Comment: Using GPU timers for this call alone is also pretty much meaningless. I don't expect any GPU commands to be generated directly from this call. State validation is typically deferred until the next draw call.